# Docker extra hosts alias

Tags: docker

I have a setup where a docker service send some urls to an application. Those urls point to other service. Those urls have the form `host.docker.internal:9000/...`. On the machine where the application is running I use to have a line in the hosts file pointing where to find the service (`host.docker.internal 172.11.0.1`), which used to work fine.

Now I am moving the application to its own container and that trick doesn't work anymore. So in the container where my application is running I need to set an extra_hosts line which points to the service which runs on port 9000, but this is not feasible as its internal ip changes each restart.

Is there any way I can make an alias of host.docker.internal to another name?

Comment: Can you change the application configuration, maybe by setting environment variables to point to the other services' Docker-internal host names?  You shouldn't usually need to set `extra_hosts:` or edit `/etc/hosts` files.

Comment: I agree I shouldn't need to use extra_hosts, but the application is designed as it is and I can't change that, at least not easily. I know the other services internal hostname, but the issue is that one of the services send urls with the said scheme (host.docker.internal:9000/...) and my application needs to fetch stuff there.